# How to trigger a mouse move event from jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events, mousemove

I'm trying to manually trigger a `mousemove` event with jQuery. Demo in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qJJQW/

From other similar posts on Stack Overflow it seems that this should work. Why isn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use jQuery to bind the mousemove event:

```
$(function () {
   $("#test").on("mousemove", youCantHandleTheFunc);

    $('#button').click(function () {
        $('#test').trigger('mousemove', {type:'custom mouse move'});
    });
});

function youCantHandleTheFunc (e,customE) {
    if (customE != undefined) {
         e = customE;   
    }
    $('#result').html(e.type);
}
```

[**Your updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/qJJQW/5/)

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. I thought that might be it but then stumbled on this line in the jQuery docs `"To trigger handlers bound via jQuery without also triggering the native event, use .triggerHandler() instead."` which says to me that the alternative `trigger()` function does trigger the native events (maybe my understanding of native events is limited. :)

Answer (score 4):

jQuery's `trigger()` only triggers event handlers set with jQuery ?

```
$(function(){
    $('#test').on('mousemove', youCantHandleTheFunc); 

    $('#button').click(function(){
        $('#test').trigger('mousemove',{type:'custom mouse move'});
    });
});

function youCantHandleTheFunc(e,customE){
    if (customE!=undefined){
         e=customE;   
    }
    $('#result').html(e.type);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qJJQW/3/)